# Looking for XX/XX@-@XX:XX@-@ in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would to like to remove all characters that have this format: XX/XX@-@XX:XX@-@, where X could be any number.

I try to resolve that with this program:

```
Sub Date_Time()
'
' It will looking for "/" and delete 16 characters, starting 3 characters before "/".
' It should remove all Date and Time in the file.
'
With Sheets("Get_Command")
.Select

Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For Lrow = 1 To Lastrow Step 1

        Set find2 = Cells(Lrow, 1).Find("/", LookIn:=xlValues) ' Look for "/"

        If Not find2 Is Nothing Then

            Cells(Lrow, 17).FormulaR1C1 = "=SEARCH(""/"",RC[-16])"
            Cells(Lrow, 18).FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-17],RC[-1]-2,RC[-1]+13)"

            Cells(Lrow, 1).Replace _
                What:=Cells(Lrow, 18).Value, Replacement:="", _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns


        End If

    Next Lrow

Columns("Q:R").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End With

End Sub
```

The program is, it is looking just for the first "/" in the row and could have some "/" that it is not in the format that I want to remove.

Someone have some idea how can I fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand, but if you're looking for something with such a specific pattern, I'd suggest using Regular Expressions for doing the replacing....

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~chenx/reading/VBA/vb_regexp.html) to Regex operations in VBA.

Comment: I didn't understand the RE, what I'm lookink for in the rows is the date and time, and it will show always in the same format but not necessary the same day and time. I don't know if I was clear enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Regex expression your looking for is:

```
[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\@\-\@[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\@\-\@
```

---

Here is a generic function taken from [here](http://strugglingtoexcel.wordpress.com/2013/12/08/introduction-to-regular-expressions-in-vba/):

```
Function RegExpReplace(ByVal WhichString As String, _
                        ByVal pattern As String, _
                        ByVal ReplaceWith As String, _
                        Optional ByVal IsGlobal As Boolean = True, _
                        Optional ByVal IsCaseSensitive As Boolean = True) As String
    'Declaring the object
    Dim objRegExp As Object

    'Initializing an Instance
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    'Setting the Properties
    objRegExp.Global = IsGlobal
    objRegExp.pattern = pattern
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = Not IsCaseSensitive

    'Execute the Replace Method
    RegExpReplace = objRegExp.Replace(WhichString, ReplaceWith)

End Function
```

---

Test sub looks like this:

```
Sub testRegex()
    Dim str As String
    str = "My 11/22@-@11:22@-@ test"

    MsgBox (str)

    Dim pattern As String
    pattern = "[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\@\-\@[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\@\-\@"

    MsgBox (RegExpReplace(str, pattern, ""))
End Sub
```

---

Results: first message box shows the unaltered string

[image]

The last message box shows the string with the pattern removed that matched the regex

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer! =) I'm going to study what did you show and see if I really got the idea! I tought that I was getting use with programming but maybe not! hahahaha

Comment: Here is a post that can help provide you with more detail on [Regex for Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/2521004).